# не могу подключиться к Docker

Tags: docker, виртуальная-машина, connect

Не могу сбилдить с докером приложение, подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема?

Может из-за отсутствия virtual machine path (второй скрин)? Если да, то что туда следует вписать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: а у вас запущено Docker for Windows?